# Directory does not exist with FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter

I use FileWriter for create a file.
I have  an error Directory does not exist 
I think that FileWriter create the directory if it did not exist

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
```

Comment: well, **apparently it doesn't!**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`java.io.FileWriter` does not create missing directories in the file path.

To create the directories you could do the following:

```
final File file = new File(sFileName);
final File parent_directory = file.getParentFile();

if (null != parent_directory)
{
    parent_directory.mkdirs();
}

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

Comment: would it be worth it to add a `&& !parent_directory.exists()` to the `if` check?

Comment: @MattFelzani, you could but `mkdirs()` only returns `true` it if it created the directory, which implies it performs an existence check itself.

Answer (score 2):

From the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String%29), we can conclude that FileWriter does not create a DIR if it does not exist:

> ### FileWriter
>
> ```
> public FileWriter(String fileName)
>       throws IOException
> ```
>
> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name.
>
> **Parameters:**
>      `fileName` - String The system-dependent filename.
>
> **Throws:**
>      `IOException` - if the named file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason

Comment: Yes sir. It is a feasible way of doing it. Regards!